# What git strategy for maintaining code that an upstream repository does not welcome

Tags: c++, git, data-distribution-service

We have a set of DDS adapters written in C++ with necessary callbacks and pub/sub message functions to send data back and forth across messaging buses between two pieces of software.

The maintainers of the adapters are only interested in maintaining callbacks and functions they use for their own purposes. But our team runs our own tool using these adapters and we need one additional callback and pub/sub message function that the upstream maintainers do not.

Until now, we've been using a fork of their upstream, where we chop the functionality we do not need, add the functionality we do need, and then instantiate both sets of adapters to manage their respective communications over the buses.

The problem that's increasingly apparent is the divergence of the structural code, e.g. a certain adapter class is modified by the maintainers to have an entirely new class structure, albeit with the same data members for the time being. Our old version is probably going to work...until it doesn't.

What git strategy could we use on our modified set of adapters to both keep the structural code up to date with the upstream, while also keeping our local changes and additional functionality?

Comment: I am not sure how git can help there. If upstream does changes incompatible with your local modifications, how do you handle it?

Comment: git can't help you _solve_ it. If upstream doesn't want to accept your work, there's not much you can do to force them. All you can do is what you are doing: manage it downstream.

Comment: Git will synchronize the code and be fairly flexible in applying incremental patches etc... but it seems your problem is with code structure, not really git. If they change their code you are just going to have to change yours to accommodate. I don't think there is a magic bullet except you may be able to decouple your designs as much as possible from their designs that yours rely on.

Comment: git will not help you with this. Can't you contact the upstream maintainers and maybe financially sponsor them so that they have some additional benefit in working with your team and also support your use cases in the future?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I should have been more clear that I wasn't "only" looking for a git strategy, but perhaps a higher level strategy that takes git or repository functionalities into account.